# How do I do a push deploy with Rocketeer?

Tags: php, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

It seems the standard way to deploy with Rocketeer is to do a pull deploy, that is, it will do a git clone from the server you are deploying to. What I want to do is push a set of files after having done a build on a CI server to the server being deployed to.

The reason I want to do this is that usually my projects have lots of extra stuff not required for production. I usually like to construct a build folder and run a build script that packages a final product. I want to use Rocketeer to push the results to staging/production servers. It was suggested in this article it can be done: [Deploying PHP Applications with Rocketeer and Docker](https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/deploying-php-applications-with-rocketeer-and-docker)

However, after reading the rocketeer documentation there is nothing that speaks to that strategy and its seems a bit against the grain to try. I'm open to ideas given my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the author of the article, I owe you a clarification. I mentioned those two types of deployment paradigms in a general sense just to introduce the different concepts. As I am aware of, Rocketeer supports only "pull" deployments. Sorry for the confusion!

For deploying the generated files to your server from a CI, I think the most straightforward way is to usea tool like scp, rsync or just download it from S3 if you're storing your built package in a bucket.

Comment: I like the idea of having something like rocketeer to manage release and shared folders, etc. And the flexibility to add in some additional automation with tasks, etc. I'm looking at Magallanes which seems to do what I want. You can push folders, plus enjoy some of the functionality I just mentioned.